# Topology - Neighborhood

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $\tau$=$\{X,\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$.  Being so, why is $\{a,c\}$ a neighborhood of a, but not a neighborhood of c?

Comment: Can you answer the first part of your question? Why is $\{a, c\}$ a neighborhood of $a$?

Comment: Write down the definition of neighborhood. It should pretty much follow from there.

Comment: because $\{a\} \in \{a\} \subseteq \{a,c\}$

Answer (score 4):

The set $\{a,c\}$ is a nbhd of $a$ because it contains an open set that contains $a$, namely, $\{a\}$. It is not a nbhd of $c$, because it does not contain any open set that contains $c$. The only open set that contains $c$ is $X$ itself, so $X$ is the only nbhd of $c$.

Another way to say it is that $\{a,c\}$ is a nbhd of $a$ because $a$ is in the interior of $\{a,c\}$: $a\in\{a\}\subseteq\{a,c\}$, and $\{a\}\in\tau$. The point $c$, however, is not in the interior of $\{a,c\}$: there is no $U\in\tau$ such that $c\in U\subseteq\{a,c\}$.

Comment: So if $\{c\}$ was in the topology would $\{a,c\}$ be a neighboorhood then?

Comment: @Randomstop: Yes, it would. It would also be a nbhd of $c$ if the set $\{a,c\}$ itself were in $\tau$.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but what does being in the topology cause $\{c\}$ to be?  Also, what would happen if $\{a,c\}$ is in the topology?

Comment: @Randomstop: I’m not sure quite what you’re asking. If $\{c\}$ were in $\tau$, then $\{c\}$ would be an open set in the space, and similarly for $\{a,c\}$.

Comment: That answered the first part or at least answered what I was wondering.  For the second part.  If $\{a,c\}$ was in the topology and $\{c\}$ was not in the topology, would $\{a,c\}$ be a neighborhood of $\{c\}$ or no?

Comment: @Randomstop: If $\{a,c\}\in\tau$, then $\{a,c\}$ is a nbhd of $a$ and a nbhd of $c$.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much!  I really REALLY appreciate all your answers and helping me better understand topology!

Comment: @Randomstop: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The set $\{a,c\}$ does not contain an open set that contains $c$. (It does contain an open set that contains $a$.)